# How to half overlap images in android constraint layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-view, android-constraintlayout

Is there any way to place an images half is on top of another image using only constraint layout. I know it can be done using relative and frame layouts but in the case of constraint layout is there anyway?
 prefer ways which do not require any hardcoding of heights/widths

the requirement will look like this

[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you can set layout using only constraint layout like below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"  
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_upper"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Note:** If you are using support library then you have to use **android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout** instead of **androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout**

[image]

Comment: thanks . please add some explanation it will be useful for every viewers

Comment: Using layout_constraintGuide_percent, you can set imageview height dynamically as per your requirment

Comment: the guideline is not at the vertical  center of that image how to fix that. i have tried vertical bias too but it's not working

Comment: In above code , If you set -> app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" in your guideline then above code automatically set your image in center

Comment: android:orientation="horizontal" in guideline means set that ratio vertically in screen

Comment: there is no problem with the guide line . but the image is not divided half by the guid line

Comment: which image you want in center..? big one or small..?

Comment: I want the small image's half part is over the guideline and another half under the guideline , the guid line divides the image by half .in some devices it's working properly by setting toptotopof guidline and bottomtobottom of guidline but some devices it's not working properly . i tried bias values but still it's not working

Answer (score 10):

**Simplest way**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="#c2b6c2">

    </ImageView>


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/appBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBar"
         />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@color/colorAccent" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:id="@+id/marginSpacer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/my_imageView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/my_imageView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/my_imageView" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/marginSpacer" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**OR THIS**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/imageviewanchor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/subject"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:src="@color/colorAccent"
                android:text="Thi"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/viewB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/imageviewanchor"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: he only wants constraint layout as parent...not constraint and linear mixed..and if he wants in linear then his question has no meaning

Answer (score 3):

Check it out margin. Put it in your ConstraintLayout.

```
  <android.support.constraint.Guideline
     android:id="@+id/guideline"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
  <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
     app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"/>

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:background="@color/colorAccent"
     app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline"/>
 <ImageView
     android:layout_width="100dp"
     android:layout_height="100dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
     android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
     android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
     android:src="#000000"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way just have to use two line code.

> card_1 card_2
>
> ```
> In constraints of card_2 add two constraints:
> app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/card_1"
> app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card_1"
> ```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#69F"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/card_1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/card_1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/card_1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card_1" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpsDT.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_upper"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.371" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    enter code here
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:weightSum="2"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        >
                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1.2"
                            >
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:weightSum="2"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                >
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:background="@drawable/bg"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                >
                            </LinearLayout>
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/laytop"
                                >
                            </LinearLayout>
                            </LinearLayout>
                           <ImageView
                               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                               android:background="@drawable/placeholder"
                               android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                               >

                           </ImageView>
                        </RelativeLayout>
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="0.8"
                            >

                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
```