# How to position a View offset of its parent layout and make it visible?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make a layout like this (left image), however the result is this (right image):

[image: android-layout]

As you can see, the top `ImageView` is top-half-cropped. I'm using a `ConstraintLayout` and using these 2 lines to center the `ImageView` to the top:

```xml
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

This is the complete layout file:

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"            
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/foo_bar" />

    <TextView ... />

    <TextView ... />

    <Button .../>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe this answer could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49320209/9932194

Comment: A View will always be rendered inside its parent. So if you want to have a semi circle on top you can only make the upper part of the parent transparent (except for the semicircle).